# How do I get top 3 unique names from list of dict and make count of it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have response like,

```
resp = [{**"NR": "0"**,"Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "11"}, 
            {"NR": "10","Code": "10_humans","Cnt": "1"},
            {"NR": "1000","Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "120"}, 
            {**"NR": "0"**,"Code": "10_humans","Cnt": "12"},
             {**"NR": "0"**,"Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "15"},
             {**"NR": "0"**,"Code": "50_animals","Cnt": "20"}]
```

from it, if "NR" is "0" from unique Code from the above list of dict then need to take count and add that count against the unique code. like that need to take top three counts
output sample: count of cnt,

```
"10_humans" = 12  (NR Zero)
"4_RESOURCE" = 15 (NE zero)
"50_animals" = 20 (NE Zero)
```

I tried:

```
def se_conc(response):
    cnt = 0
    list = []

    def key_func(k):
         return k['Code']
   INFO = sorted(resp, key=y_func)
   for k, v in groupby(INFO, y_func):
            print("codes:", k)
            print("v:", v)
            list.append(k)
            print("listcode", list)

            for key in list:
                if resp['NR'] == "0":
                    print("NR is 0:", k)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Take a look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going for anything complex, a sweet and simple solution would be

```
>>> resposne = [{"NR": "0","Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "12"}, 
            {"NR": "10","Code": "10_humans","Cnt": "1"},
            {"NR": "1000","Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "120"}, 
            {"NR": "0","Code": "10_humans","Cnt": "12"},
             {"NR": "0","Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "15"},
             {"NR": "0","Code": "10_humans","Cnt": "20"}]

>>> db = dict()

>>> for dct in resposne:
...     if dct['NR'] == '0':
...         db[dct['Code']] = db.get(dct['Code'], 0) + int(dct['Cnt'])

>>> db
{'4_RESOURCE': 27, '10_humans': 32}
```

Here you loop through the elements of `resposne` list, check if `'NR'` value is `'0'`, if yes, set the value of `'Code'` as `key` in `db`.

- `db.get(dct['Code'], 0)`

^ this code will try to get the value of `dct['Code']` from `db`, but for the first iteration `db` will be empty, so in order to avoid a `KeyError` (`None` in this case) we pass a default value of `0`. So for the first iteration it will be:

```
for dct in resposne:
# for first iteration dct = {"NR": "0","Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "12"}
    if dct['NR'] == '0': # This will be True as seen above
        db[dct['Code'] ] = db.get(dct['Code'], 0) + int(dct['Cnt'])
      # db["4_RESOURCE"] = db.get("4_RESOURCE", 0) + int("12")
      #                    ^ but there is no key in db yet
      #                      so this will essentially be 0
      #                  = 0 + 12 = 12
```

Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: can we covert defaultdict(int) into python Dictionary.  
output : {'4_RESOURCE': 27, '10_humans': 32} this only in type =dict

Comment: i am new in python so can u pls help to make this code understandable by suggesting line by line

Comment: Sure, in a moment.

Comment: Sayandip Dutta, if we want to take top 3 or top 2 count, then what should need to do..

Answer (score 0):

I get what you want to do. I am not sure if those '**' are actually coming out in your response or not. I wrote an example that does work. You would only need to write a single if statement. I just wrote them repeatedly to test adding the different responses.

```
NR_not_zero = 0
NE_not_zero = 0

if resposne['Code'] == "4_RESOURCE" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    if resposne['NR'] == '0':
        NR_not_zero = NR_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])
elif resposne['Code'] == "10_humans" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    NE_not_zero = NE_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])

print('NR = ',NR_not_zero)
print('NE = ',NE_not_zero)
print('___________________')

resposne = {"NR": "0","Code": "10_humans","Cnt": "12"}

if resposne['Code'] == "4_RESOURCE" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    if resposne['NR'] == '0':
        NR_not_zero = NR_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])
elif resposne['Code'] == "10_humans" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    NE_not_zero = NE_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])

print('NR = ',NR_not_zero)
print('NE = ',NE_not_zero)
print('___________________')


resposne = {"NR": "0","Code": "4_RESOURCE","Cnt": "15"}

if resposne['Code'] == "4_RESOURCE" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    if resposne['NR'] == '0':
        NR_not_zero = NR_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])
elif resposne['Code'] == "10_humans" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    NE_not_zero = NE_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])

print('NR = ',NR_not_zero)
print('NE = ',NE_not_zero)
print('___________________') 

resposne = {"NR": "0","Code": "10_humans","Cnt": "20"}

if resposne['Code'] == "4_RESOURCE" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    if resposne['NR'] == '0':
        NR_not_zero = NR_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])
elif resposne['Code'] == "10_humans" and resposne['NR'] == '0':
    NE_not_zero = NE_not_zero + int(resposne["Cnt"])

print('NR = ',NR_not_zero)
print('NE = ',NE_not_zero)
print('___________________')
```